# Google Monitoring Query Language Metric Too many time series identifier columns

Tags: google-cloud-platform, metrics, mql, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm trying to create a query in GCP Monitoring with the Google Monitoring Language ([MQL Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference)). The metrics are from istio ([Istio Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_istio?hl=de)).

As soon as I start working with the metric, I get the following error:

```
Line 1: Too many time series identifier columns created with column 'metric.response_code' from 'istio.io/service/server/response_bytes'.
```

For example, when I try the following:

```
fetch k8s_container::istio.io/service/server/response_bytes
```

I tried to filter, group, select, or remap the `time series identifier`, but the error above stays the same.

Does anybody have an idea of how to solve this or the same issue?

Comment: Hello, I was able to replicate your issue. I suggest you post your case on Google's public issue tracker (issuetracker.google.com) so they can give you one on one service

Comment: This is a known bug for which a fix will be available soon.